# show and hide list column in NewForm.aspx based on checkbox

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom list with some columns in sharePoint, that one of them is (yes / no) checkbox, I want to show  2 columns of list in NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx  based on selecting check box.if user select checkbox 2 columns should be fade in.
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to build the form in Infopath. There you can create rules on the fields. So for example if check box = yes, then show/hide field.

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/06/automatically-create-infopath-forms-sharepoint-form-library-sharepoint-designer-workflow/